# Out of range monitor - Ubuntu 22.04LTS

Tags: boot, server

I’ve read through similar posts and none of the suggestions seem to be working so I thought I’d start my own thread.

I’m trying to do a clean install from usb post boot of Ubuntu server on my machine.

Machine has no OS, completely clean drive only thing I have done to it is update the bios to its on its latest.

When booting from usb I get two options;

Try or do install Ubuntu server
Test memory

Then press e to edit commands and c to get into grub.

When selecting top option after 4/5 seconds I’ll get an out of range error on my monitor. A 1080p ASus connected via vga to my server.

I have gone into grub and used the command “videoinfo” to have 1 single output.

“Legend: mask/position=red/green/blue/reserved”

It’s my first time with Linux so having to troubleshoot right out the gate is pretty tricky. Any help will be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: Thought I was being smart by connecting up my 22 year old CRT monitor so that the resolution would be good. It wasn't still out of range - Though the screen just went black rather than say out of range . It happened at the same point.

Comment: Have now tried to edit the command for launching Ubuntu. 

Pressing e in the menu I can change the set gfxmode=keep.To set gfxmode=640x480. I have also tried vga=769 to bypass it. Same issue both times.